# Replace each word with another word in a given text in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have to make a function which replaces each word (x), with another word(y), in a given text(**string). Can I replace them directly in the given text? Or should I make a new array and make the replacements there? However and don't know how to continue.
The code I wrote is:

```
void operation_2(char x[100], char y[100], char **string, int N)
{
    int len = 0;
    char *word;
    char s[12] = " .,?!\"';:";
    char **newstring = (char **)malloc(N * sizeof(char *));

    for (i = 0; i<= N; i++) {
            word = strtok(string[i], s);
            while (word != NULL) {
                    if (strcmp(word, x) == 0) {
                            len = strlen(string[i]) - strlen(x) + strlen(y);
                            newstring[i] = (char *)malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

Comment: If it is an assignment, then good on you to work yourself. If this is for work, then [how about this](http://www.engineersgarage.com/c-language-programs/replacing-word-text)?

Comment: I will try. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new string, it'll be able to take any string (string literal, an array on the stack, a static array, an array on the heap) as input, but it won't be as memory efficient.

If you want maximum memory efficiency, then you can modify the target string in-place, but you'll have restrictions depending on where the input string is stored.

- string literal or possibly a const static array: you can't do anything do anything with it
- stack, or static: you can shrink it
- heap: you can `realloc` it (shrink it or expand it)

The `memmove` function might come in handy if you decide to modify the string in place.

---

Keep in mind however, that:

1. There's no such thing as array arguments in C. They always decay to pointers.
2. strtok will modify it's input, so you'd need to make at least one copy if you decide to go with `strtok`

Comment: The text is stored in heap. I tried with `strstr` too but it looks like it doesn't work as i want. For example if I have something like this "John has to buy ten apples" and i search for the word "apple", that function will take "apples" as a good word. For my purpose must be a difference between apples and apple.

Comment: Then, after you've found a match with strstr, you need to look around it to determine if it is indeed a match an resume search if it's not. (It's kind of a pain in the butt to do all of this in C.)

Comment: Ok. I will try to do something concrete. Thanks for help. Hope i won't face the most adored error "Segemntation fault".